# How to include html fragment using thymeleaf using an API

Tags: java, thymeleaf, microservices, uicomponents

Can we include HTML fragments in thymeleaf using an API service?

We are in the process of transforming our monolithic application into microservice architecture. this is being a Portal application integrated with many downstream systems via web service (SOAP/ RESTful)/ jms, we are trying to vertically slice the application along with front end step by step making current monolithic application as a strangler application.

Also this has a CMS integration as well to provide contents update functionality  for non technical staff at their will.

Now the challenge is to provide unique user experience across functionalities through multiple web applications and at same time avoiding static resource duplicates across these applications.

After some researches I thought of introducing these common parts of the applications (header/footer/ library js/ theme css) as  components and including them in the pages using common templates across applications via an API.

This will allow me to avoid resource duplication and maintain consistency across multiple applications.

i'm planning to use thymeleaf as template if possible but still could not come across any reference which it allows to include html fragments using a service end point.

please share if you have any reference to achieve above using thymeleaf or any other good mechanism to achieve above desired goal.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good approach. What if one of the client web applications needs a slightly different visualization? What about just exposing the data via e.g. a REST-API? How many different client web applications are there - is it worth the trouble? ;-)

Comment: Thanks @JanTheGun. we can have multiple templates to maintain multiple visualizations if requires. I hope with your above approach, it is required to maintain a monolithic UI. if we need to deliver changes for UI aspects of each applications (search/ user registration/ etc.) along with backend functionality separately, then It would be difficult to apply them independently at a will if UI is monolithic. avoid this bottleneck has been a challenge which we are struggling to resolve.